# Is there a command to see how many jobs a certain user has in a queue?

Tags: linux, queue

I know commands, like qsub, qstat -a, qstat -an, etc.

But how can I find how many jobs a single user has in the queue (not all necessarily running) at any given time?

Comment: I think this question is better suited for [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Super User](http://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
qstat -u user_name[@host][,user_name[@host],...]
```

You could list a single user

**Edit:** In that case I don't know. You could still use some shell tricks to count the number of lines with specific pattern (eg user_name) but that would be indirect. For example:

```
qstat | grep user_name | wc -l
```